# How to do : AjaxControlToolkit AjaxFileUpload throw exception OnUpdateComplete Event

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using the AjaxFileUpload control in my project.
But in the OnUploadComplete event, I will save the file and do something in the database.

If these two operation throw a exception, how can I make the AjaxFileUpload fail?
Instead it show "Uploaded", how can I put a error message there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can handle clientside events of asyncfileupload.
here is a good example
http://www.ajaxprojects.com/ajax/tutorialdetails.php?itemid=965

Comment: The ajaxfileuplaod is different from asyncfileupload.